# In the newer Linux, which function in ext4 is responsible for read?

Tags: linux, filesystems, system-calls, vfs, ext4

Conventional filesystems create a **struct file_operations** structure to implement the VFS functions. For example, in the ext4 (Linux 4.0 and before) the **struct file_operations ext4_file_operations** make the read pointer point to new_sync_read.

Linux 4.0 [/fs/ext4/file.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0.9/source/fs/ext4/file.c#L630)

```
const struct file_operations ext4_dax_file_operations = {
    .read       = new_sync_read,
    .read_iter  = generic_file_read_iter,
     ....
}
```

However, in Linux 4.1 and later, there is no such assignment for the read pointer, but a splice_read pointer is added.

Linux 4.1 [/fs/ext4/file.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.1.22/source/fs/ext4/file.c#L635)

```
const struct file_operations ext4_file_operations = {   
    .read_iter  = generic_file_read_iter,
    .splice_read    = generic_file_splice_read,
    ...
}
```

But the **struct file_operations** defined in "/include/linux/fs.h" still has the read pointer. So, which function in ext4 now is responsible for the conventional read function?

Comment: I now think the conventional read is directly implemented by the read_iter in newer versions, as in old versions it is indirect implemented by read_iter. If this is right, what is the role of read pinter of VFS in newer versions?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been quite old, but I was actually looking for the same thing and found the answer.

In Linux 5.8, inside `vfs_read()` function,

```
if (file->f_op->read)
    ret = file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos);
else if (file->f_op->read_iter)
    ret = new_sync_read(file, buf, count, pos);
```

these lines find whether `.read` is defined by `file`'s file operations (`f_op`).
If not, `.read_iter` calls in `new_sync_read()` will handle the read operation instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested by writing a new file system and found if we initialise both pointers then `.read` is called if I use **cat** command. If I use **cat** command without initialising `.read` but initialising `.read_iter` the `.read_iter` is called.